# Wordpress Custom Plugin Upload Image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am writing a custom wordpress plugin that let the user upload a image to a folder. 
And I'm having problem saving the actual image to a folder.

This is my myplugin.php

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'Home Page', 'Home Page', 'manage_options', 'homepage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
}

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo '<h1>Settings</h1>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    echo '<table>';

    echo '<tr><td>Image 1</td><td><input type="file" name="file1" size="40"></td></tr>';    
    echo '<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></td></tr>';     
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</form>';
 }
```

This is my process.php, and I do not see the image inside my wp upload folder. Please help!

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cul_center"]["tmp_name"], wp_upload_dir().$_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Whats `cul_center` key is?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PHP native functions for this.

Wordpress provide [wp_handle_upload()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) function to handle uploads and move them `/uploads/year/month/` explicitly.

Usage (in your case):

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' ); // require file.php

$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file1']; // your file input

$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false ); // you need to do this according to docs

$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides ); //let it handle uploads

if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    var_dump( $movefile); // will print associative array of file attributes.
}
```